# How to asynchronously populate a field in an ObjectListView

Tags: c#, .net, objectlistview

I am using an ObjectListView and trying to figure out how to correctly populate a field/column data asynchronously.

ObjectListView uses the concept of an "AspectSetter" which allows you to provide the content of the row's field data like so:

```
tlist.GetColumn(0).AspectGetter = delegate(Person x) { return x.Name; };
```

In my case, the field I am returning takes some time to calculate:

```
tlist.GetColumn(0).AspectGetter = delegate(Person x) { return SomeCalculation(); };
```

What would be the best approach to return the field data without blocking the UI and also allow the rest of the field data to be populated?

Comment: To populate the field asynchronously without blocking the UI, you can use `async/await` with a delegate or lambda function.

Comment: Thanks, @AmitMohanty. That would be my assumed solution as well, however ObjectListView does not accept an async method as a delegate.

Comment: Use a background thread to execute the async method and update the ObjectListView with the result. You can use `Task.Run` to run the async method on a background thread and then use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to update the UI on the main thread.

Comment: Not sure if you're answering in the context of ObjectListView. OLV works by setting a delegate to retrieve a field's data. This is a blocking call, so where would I put my async code?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `async` method to perform the calculation and return the result.

```
private async Task<string> CalculateAsync(Person person)
{
    // Simulate a delay, replace with your actual asynchronous operation.
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    // Perform your actual calculation here.
    string result = "Result";

    return result;
}


tlist.GetColumn(0).AspectGetter = delegate(Person x)
{
    // Use Task.Run to run the async method on a background thread.
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        string result = await CalculateAsync(x);

        // Use Invoke or BeginInvoke to update the UI on the main thread.
        tlist.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            // Update the ObjectListView with the calculated result.
            tlist.RefreshObject(x);
        }));

        return result;
    });
};
```

In the above code the calculation is performed on a background thread, preventing it from blocking the UI, and the `ObjectListView` is updated with the result on the UI thread when the calculation is completed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution, @Amit but there's something missing here. The resulting data that gets put in the field is "System.Thread.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[System.String]"

Comment: It's not possible to assign an async delegate to AspectGetter.